# Tab fragment error occurring and fragment parent activity has been destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[image]

Error occurs when switching from one tab to another, the Main Fragment Activity has been destroyed.

My fragment child Profile_album_details code:

```
case R.id.ib_photo_delete:
        String stringiq = "";
        NewTask.iq = new CustomIQ("<albummanagement xmlns='naseebalbum'           action='deletepicture'><albumname>"+album.getAlbum_name()+"</albumname><picturetitle>"+picture.getTitle()+"</picturetitle></albummanagement>");
        NewTask.iq.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
        new NewTask(context).execute();
        while(NewTask.connection.isAuthenticated() == false){}
        Profile_album_details.pictures.remove(imageno);
        Profile_display_photo.pictures = Profile_album_details.pictures;
        new MainActivity().updateTab(new Profile_album_details(), R.id.tab2,true);
```

Main activity parent fragment class:

```
public void updateTab(Fragment frg,
            int place_holder, boolean addTobackStack) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(place_holder, frg);
//      ft.setTransition(transaction);

        if(addTobackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
    }



> 10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1333)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at com.example.tabs.MainActivity.updateTab(MainActivity.java:166)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at com.example.tabs.MainActivity.launchNewFragment(MainActivity.java:175)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at adapters.Profile_display_photo.onClick(Profile_display_photo.java:164)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>     10-02 15:25:55.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you actually destroy/finish the Activity by yourself?

Comment: fragmentactivity has been destroyed after fragmenttranstitoin.commit()

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question now. `FragmentTransaction.commit()` is not executed immediately, there is a delay between when the method is called and when the actual transaction commit is executed. That's the reason why when you call the `FragmentTransaction.commit()` and then `finish()` the `Activity` you get that error, because the `Activity` is destroyed before the transaction commit is executed.

To avoid this use `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`. This should, as the name indicates, execute all the pending transactions immediately. Without seeing your whole code I would guess that the best place is before the `Activity.finish()` call, but if that doesn't work then try after the `commit()`